# how to get id form updated in django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

How to update id field in Django, for example I have this:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM school_subjects;
+----+--------+---------+-------------+
| id | name   | user_id | delete_flag |
+----+--------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | Canada |       2 |           0 |
|  2 | USA    |       2 |           0 |
+----+--------+---------+-------------+
```

If I delete them, then update again, my id will keep incrementing:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM school_subjects;
+----+--------+---------+-------------+
| id | name   | user_id | delete_flag |
+----+--------+---------+-------------+
|  3 | Canada |       2 |           0 |
|  4 | USA    |       2 |           0 |
+----+--------+---------+-------------
```

+
So how to make id field check the lowest one, and than increment it from there?

```
#models.py
class Subjects(models.Model):
    """ Subject Database """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False) #Subject Names on left-menu 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    delete_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' %(self.name, self.user.username)
```

Comment: i don't think that is how mysql autoincrementing id's work.

Comment: Why would you delete and then recreate? Why not just update the one you have?

Comment: It is not a good practice to "reuse" the ids you've deleted. Think of a scenario where you have ids 1,2,3,4,5 and then you delete 3. You can find that 3 is missing and set auto_increment to use that id, but then it will increase to id 4 and try to save the next item to an already existing id. The auto_increment mechanism is part of the DB and not Django and while it is possible to use Django to manually set the value of the id (you can use a custom id field - classname_id for example) it's better to be avoided.